# Can someone help me understanding this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Programming (JavaScript) and have trouble understanding code sometimes especially when its this complicated!

Can someone help me understand this code?

```js
const points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

for (let i = points.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
  let k = points[i]

  points[i] = points[j]
  points[j] = k
}

console.log(points);
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `k = points[i]; points[i] = points[j]; points[j] = k;` is the usual swapping of two values (`points[i]` and `points[j]`) using a third variable (`k` in this case).

Comment: _"Can someone help me understand this code?"_ - And what exactly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what parts you don't understand. We need to know how much we need to explain.

Comment: So is it any particular bit of it that you're struggling with? Essentially it's cycling backwards through the array of points and randomly shuffling the values.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I got lost from let k =points[i]

Comment: Have you tried debugging line by line through the code? When I was learning that helped me (and still helps me) figure out what's happening in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
       //creating an integer array
        const points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
        // i = points.length - 1 means i = 5 
        // loop will continuously running until loops reached to zero
       // i--. means i will decrease the value on every loop.
        for (let i = points.length -1; i > 0; i--)
        { 
            // Math.floor function round the value like  2.112  to 2
            // Math.random generate random no but under 1. like 0.5521775019207191 
            // first time i = 5 then 0.5521775019207191 * 5 = 2.7608875096 after the 
                //rounded it will become 3. 
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)  
        //creating a new variable and storing the points[i] (points[5]) means last value 
       //  of the array (100) in it.
        let k = points[i] 
        //now storing the random no in the replacement of last value of the array (100)
        points[i] = points[j] 
        //in the above 2nd line we have storing the last value of the //array (100) now we have add this value in the replacement of the index //which in generated by random no 
     //for suppose if the random no is 2 then it is storing the value //(100)  2nd index in the array
        points[j] = k
    }
```